# Über die Konstruktion "suchen zu + Inf."

Tags: phrase

Kürzlich bin ich in einem Lehrbuch auf die folgende Konstruktion gestoßen:

> Seit einiger Zeit sucht er sie zu vergessen.
>   Er sucht ihr seltsames Verhalten zu verstehen.

Da ich bisher diesen Ausdruck nie getroffen habe, gehe ich davon aus, dass er so gut wie keine Verwendung findet oder dass er überholt ist. Ist das richtig und in welchen Fällen kann diese Konstruktion verwendet werden?

Comment: Das in diesem Zusammenhang weitaus gebräuchlichere Verb ist **versuchen**. Der Rest ist ein Infinitivsatz, der nach der letzten Rechtschreibreform auch ohne Komma angehängt werden darf. Was man aber offensichtlich besser lassen sollte, denn es verwirrt den Leser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie Janka kommentierend schon so schön ausgeführt hat, ist

> suchen, etwas zu tun

synonym zu verstehen zu

> versuchen, etwas zu tun

Wobei "suchen" statt "versuchen" eher in höheren Registern der Sprache verwendet wird, sei es in der Dichtkunst, vornehmlich der älteren, sei es in sonstiger gedrechselter Rede. Der Alltagssprecher wird kaum je auf den Gedanken kommen, sich an "suchen" ohne "ver" zu versuchen.

Entsprechend dem erhöhten stilistischen Register sind auch die so beschriebenen Inhalte häufig höherfliegender Art.

> Er sucht, sie zu vergessen

(offenbar geht es hier um das höherfliegende Gefühl der Liebe) ist eine sehr typische Verwendung. Hier ist man außerdem besonders geneigt, das "ver" auszulassen, weil danach gleich noch ein "ver" kommt - von "vergessen".

Dagegen hört man sehr selten Anwendungen wie

> Er sucht, sein Auto zu reparieren.

Das ist wohl inhaltlich zu prosaisch, und es fehlt der ergänzende Motor (jaja) des doppelten "ver", das man (ver)meiden möchte.

Ähnlich übrigens, wie man sieht, mit ***meiden***:

> Er vermeidet, Unsinn zu verzapfen.
>
> Er meidet, Unsinn zu verzapfen.

Auch hier kann man das "ver" weglassen, kommt dadurch aber auch in höhere Schichten des Stils (im Beispiel leider nicht durchgehalten, das *Unsinn verzapfen* kein höherer Stil ist sondern flappsige Alltagssprache).

Manchmal sucht man auch durch Weglassen des "ver", ein Versmaß besser einzuhalten.

Comment: Bin nicht einig. *versuchen*, etwas zu tun ist immer eine konkrete Aktivität - *suchen*, etwas zu tun, ist breiter, mit u.U. vielen verschiedenen Aktionen, oder sogar gar keiner - Weil man die passende Aktion noch "sucht". Hat also nicht (nur) mit Stil zu tun.

Comment: @tofro   Da bin ich wiederum mit dir durchaus einig. Ich finde auch, dass *suchen* breiter, allgemeiner, philosophischer verstanden werden kann als *versuchen*. In den oben angeführten Beispielen (sucht/versucht, sie zu vergessen etc.) ist die Bedeutung aber doch die gleiche. Natürlich, da die Kontexte, in denen man "suchen" (statt "versuchen") sagt, oft höherfliegende sind, ist auch die Bedeutung dann oft breiter, allgemeiner, philosophischer.